# Windows 10 Version Stuck on v1909 18363.535

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

For the last few months, I've been stuck on Windows 10 v1909 18363.535 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gde8z.png).

The latest update as of writing is KB4574727. This update appears to successfully download and install up to 100% before spitting out the following error:

```
There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later.
2020-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1909 for x64-based Systems (KB4574727) - Error 0x800f0988
```

When the next windows update is released, it will fail in the same manner, as it has with every other update since KB4530684.

**Motivation** - I'd like to get to the latest windows version so that I can use WSL2.

---

Here is a list of everything I've tried so far:

1. Making sure I have enough disk space
2. Installing latest dotnet 3 and 4
3. Manually installing update via catalog: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Windows%2010%20KB4574727%20x64%201909

```
The following updates were not installed:
```

4. Verifying Filesystem Integrity:

```
sfc /scannow
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

5. windows update troubleshooter: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

```
Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem
```

6. This powershell script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-WindowsUpdateps1-e0c5eb78
7. Reset windows update services from cmd shell:

```
Net Stop bits
Net Stop wuauserv
Net Stop appidsvc
Net Stop cryptsvc
Ren %systemroot%SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak
Ren %systemroot%system32catroot2 catroot2.bak
Net Start bits
Net Start wuauserv
Net Start appidsvc
Net Start cryptsvc
```

---

Also, other windows updates (e.g. drivers, windows defender etc.) download and install fine.

I have not yet tried resetting/reinstalling windows. If there is a way to keep both my program files and personal files, that might be the next thing I try.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> If there is a way to keep both my program files and personal files ...
> ?

Since you done many appropriate things, now use Windows 10 Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally. Use the option to Keep Everything.