# How to enable WSL2 , DISM can't find it on my updated Win10

Tags: windows-10, wsl2, dism

I followed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Here is the output of the first command

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572

Image Version: 10.0.19042.631


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.
```

Log is here: https://gist.github.com/geocine/e4606b1e6fdbe8b42402207e2d88a258

Clearly my windows is updated and shoult not throw this error so I ran `sfc`

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

I tried to run `RestoreHealth` for `DISM` but always stops at `19.2`

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572

Image Version: 10.0.19042.631

[===========                19.2%                          ]
Error: 3

The system cannot find the path specified.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Log is here: https://gist.github.com/geocine/12abf02e9e8d9f300a58bbcdc9374eac

But component store is not corrupted

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
```

It shows this

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572

Image Version: 10.0.19042.631

No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is upgrade to 21H2. Based on the build, even the version you are on hasn't been updated in months.  The fact DISM is failing strongly suggests your WinSxS folder is corrupt.  10.0.19042 is 20H2, which is NOT supported; the current 20H2 build is 10.0.19042.1415.  **KB5008212 was released eight months ago.**  We will need more information about the reason your system is 8 months out of date and NOT running at least 21H1

Comment: After doing the things @Ramhound mentions.. (yes, 21H2 is where the party is).. Why are you doing the manual installation?  Enable this through the windows features GUI.  Either it will work, or you *might* get a better error message.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to update but I am getting 0x800f0988 error. I am figuring it out. 
Señor CMasMas, you will not find it on the UI on my machine

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1584985/windows-10-version-stuck-on-v1909-18363-535) suggests only performing a repair installation then upgrading can result in resolving your issues.

Comment: If your WinSxS isn’t corrupt you should be able to successfully run *dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup* without an issue. The only other possible solution other than an in-place upgrade is to reset and clear out the Windows Update cache.

Comment: I did try `/startcomponentcleanup` it completed successfully unfortunately I still can do an update and WSL still not found on component store.